# How to query for entities using a list of ancestor keys

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gql

I have the following data model in Google Cloud Datastore:

```
Parent:
  - name

Child:
  - ancestor: Parent
  - name
```

I have a list of `Parent` keys. How can I query for all `Child` entities descending from the list of `Parent` keys ?

I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM Child WHERE __key__ HAS ANCESTOR Key(Parent, 'abc'), Key(Parent, 'dfe')
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM Child WHERE __key__ HAS ANCESTOR [Key(Parent, 'abc'), Key(Parent, 'dfe')]
```

and neither select statements work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Datastore queries can operate on at most one ancestor, so you'd have to run this as two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM Child WHERE __key__ HAS ANCESTOR Key(Parent, 'abc')
SELECT * FROM Child WHERE __key__ HAS ANCESTOR Key(Parent, 'dfe')
```

and merge the results.

Or if you can get away with fetching *all* `Child` entities, you could run:

```
SELECT * FROM Child
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't get away with fetching all, because I need to filter them out. Looks like this is the best possible solution which means one query per ancestor. :(